# Generating addition combinations from an int list in python

Tags: python, combinations, addition

I have an array of floats of unknown length. The numbers range from 0-1000.
I'm looking to generate every possible addition combination from those numbers that is less than a user defined value and append them in another list.
for example, if numlist =[200,350,510] and the defined maximum is 1200,
I want to generate the combinations:

200, 400(numlist[1]*2+numlist[2]*0+numlist[3]*0), 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 350, 700(200*0+350*2+510*0), 1050(200*0+350*0+510*2), 510, 1020, 550(200*1+350*1), 900(200*1+350*2)  etc.

The goal of this program is to check a large file of floats, and print if an individual float can be constructed using the numbers in numlist. I think that the most efficient way to do is would be to find all the combinations first, then to check if the float-combination==0  Is there a systematic or another way to do this? There is no set length to numlist.

Comment: This is a classic dynamic-programming problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

Comment: This is sometimes known as the _invoices problem_; it's closely related to the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Your problem is a little easier than the general invoices problem, since you don't have to deal with negative values.

Comment: Simply generating all combinations, summing & testing them is ok for very small sets of data, but for larger data sets this will be _very_ slow. There is no known efficient algorithm for this problem that works on all data sets. But if you have "nice" data you can try a greedy algorithm: sort the data and build combinations starting with the largest items, summing as you go. If the sum of your current sequence equals the desired total, you're done. If the sequence sum is too big, you can stop generating combinations that start with that sequence. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a dynamic-programming example:

```
def make_combo_dict(nums, max_):
    nums = sorted(set(nums))
    prev = {0: [""]}    # base state: no combinations
    for num in nums:
        nxt = defaultdict(list)
        for total, ways in prev.items():
            # k = 0
            nxt[total] = ways
            # k > 0
            max_k = (max_ - total) // num
            for k in range(1, max_k + 1):
                nxt[total + k*num].extend(
                    "{}{}{}*{}"
                    .format(way, " + " if way else "", k, num)
                    for way in ways
                )
        prev = nxt
    return prev
```

which runs like

```
>>> combos = make_combo_dict([350, 200, 500, 510], 1200)

>>> for total,ways in sorted(combos.items()):
...     print("{:>4d}: {}".format(total, ", ".join(ways)))
   0: 
 200: 1*200
 350: 1*350
 400: 2*200
 500: 1*500
 510: 1*510
 550: 1*350 + 1*200
 600: 3*200
 700: 2*350
 710: 1*200 + 1*510
 750: 1*350 + 2*200
 800: 4*200
 850: 1*350 + 1*500
 860: 1*350 + 1*510
 900: 2*350 + 1*200, 2*200 + 1*500
 910: 2*200 + 1*510
 950: 1*350 + 3*200
1000: 5*200
1010: 1*500 + 1*510
1020: 2*510
1050: 3*350
1060: 1*350 + 1*200 + 1*510
1100: 2*350 + 2*200, 3*200 + 1*500
1110: 3*200 + 1*510
1150: 1*350 + 4*200
1200: 6*200, 1*200 + 2*500, 2*350 + 1*500
```